# Sails.JS: AUTO INCREMENT Implementation Failed

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm developing a Sails.JS app that performs CRUD operations with a MySQL database using waterline ORM. My models have an attribute `id` set to auto-increment with the `beforeCreate` function, yet every time I try to call the `create` function, this error occurs:

> > {
> >         "error": {
> >             "name": "UsageError",
> >             "code": "E_INVALID_NEW_RECORD",
> >             "details": "Missing value for required attribute `id`.  Expected a number, but instead, got: undefined"
> >         } }

Here's my model:

```
            module.exports = {
            primaryKey: 'id',
            attributes: {
                id: {
                    type: "number",
                    required: true,
                  unique: true,
                  autoIncrement: true
                },
                name: {
                   type: "string",
                   required: true
            },
           beforeCreate : function(item, next) {
    Counter.native(function(err, collection) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      collection.findAndModify(
        { _id: "id" },
        null,
        { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        { new:true, upsert:true },
        function(err, object){
          if (err) console.log(err);
          item.id = object.seq;
          next();
 }
      );
    });
  }

        };
```

Here's my model controller:

```
  module.exports = {
    create :function(req,res,next) {
      let params = {name:req.param('name') };
       model.create(params , function(err , createdData) {
         if(err){
           return res.badRequest({
           error: err
         });
       }
       else
       {
         return res.json({ added});
       }
       });
 },
```

Comment: Finally , the solution was that I had to disable required and unique properties , because the ORM can just auto-increment normal attributes , not required ones